# Why does ss label UDP ports as TCP?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iproute

All UDP connections are prefixed with TCP. Why?

```
$ ss -lunt
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port 
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:514                           *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:68                            *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                      10.0.2.15:123                           *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                      127.0.0.1:123                           *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:123                           *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:5353                          *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:53620                         *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                              *:59885                         *:*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                             :::514                          :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                             :::48693                        :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0       fe80::a00:27ff:fe13:a1df:123                          :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                            ::1:123                          :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                             :::123                          :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                             :::56496                        :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                             :::5353                         :::*     
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                   127.0.22.1:22                            *:*     
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                   127.0.80.1:443                           *:*     
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                   127.0.80.1:80                            *:*
```

Comment: Which distro and version you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: I guess your problem is related to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1063927). `ss` is part of `iproute2` and probably your version is buggy.